# How to get a link from <a> python parser

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-parsing

```
<a class="button button-mini" href="www.example-link.com.c"><b>TEXT</b></a>
```

I'm creating Python parser, and i need to get link from this tag. I tried this, but result was "None":

```
link = table.find_all('td')[1].a.href
link = table.find_all('td')[1].a.link
```

Using Beautiful Soup 4 & Python 3.5

Comment: Try `a.get('href')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's a pretty simple question where you are just missing  parameters.
It should be written as:

```
link = table.find_all('td')[1].a.get('href')
```

**Edit note**

Just noticed after answering that a user has responded to you as comment... Don't want to steal any credits.